# How to do spatial adjustment of Line features by edge snapping in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.2, spatial-adjustment

I have two polyline features of same area which are prepared based on two different raster imagery. Hence the two features are not exactly matched and has some shift.

How can I adjust them to overlay exactly one over the other? I attached the snapshot of the two polyline features.

I want Rd2 in the below imagery to adjust with Rd1 while Rd1 remains unchanged.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options to accomplish this sort of task.  A few in particular that may work for you include:

- [Align to Shape](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m800000004000000) from the advanced editing toolbar.  There is also
  a good [blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/27/align-to-shape/) and [video tutorial](http://video.arcgis.com/watch/1765/aligning-features-by-tracing) on this subject.  As
  you can see from the screenshot, the tool works pretty well.

For a more automated, less precise approach, try using:

- [Snap (editing)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000007000000)
- [Integrate (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000)
- Setting [topology](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006200000003000000) rules within a geodatabase, specifically [must be
  covered by featureclass of](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01mm0000000m000000).

There are also good blog posts on [cleaning up line data with geoprocessing](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/11/15/cleaning-up-line-data-with-geoprocessing/) and [reshaping topology edges](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/10/23/reshaping-edges/).

[image]